# Map names to column values pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## The Problem

I had a hard time phrasing this question but essentially I have a series of `X` columns that represent weights at specific points in time. Then another set of `X` columns that represent the names of those people that were measured.

That table looks like this (there's more than two columns, this is just a toy example):

| a_weight | b_weight | a_name | b_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | John | Michael |
| 1 | 2 | Jake | Michelle |
| 21 | 3 | Alice | Bob |
| 2 | 1 | Ashley | Brian |

---

## What I Want

I want to have a two columns with **the maximum weight and name** at each point in time. I want this to be vectorized because the data is a lot. I can do it using a for loop or an `.apply(lambda row: row[col])` but it is very slow.

So the final table would look something like this:

| a_weight | b_weight | a_name | b_name | max_weight | max_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | John | Michael | a_weight | John |
| 1 | 2 | Jake | Michelle | b_weight | Michelle |
| 21 | 3 | Alice | Bob | a_weight | Alice |
| 2 | 1 | Ashley | Brian | a_weight | Ashley |

---

## What I've Tried

I've been able to create a mirror `df_subset` with just the weights, then use the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) function to make a `max_weight` column:

```
df_subset = df[[c for c in df.columns if "weight" in c]]
max_weight_col = df_subset.idxmax(axis="columns")
```

This returns a column that is the `max_weight` column in the section above. Now I run:

```
df["max_name_col"] = max_weight_col.str.replace("_weight","_name")
```

and I have this:

| a_weight | b_weight | a_name | b_name | max_weight | max_name_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | John | Michael | a_weight | a_name |
| 1 | 2 | Jake | Michelle | b_weight | b_name |
| 21 | 3 | Alice | Bob | a_weight | a_name |
| 2 | 1 | Ashley | Brian | a_weight | a_name |

I basically want to run a code similar to the one below **without a for-loop**:

```
df["max_name"] = [row[row["max_name_col"]] for row in df]
```

How do I move on from here? I feel like I'm so close but I'm stuck. Any help? I'm also open to throwing away the entire code and doing something else if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that for sure just pass to `numpy` `argmax`

```
v1 = df.filter(like='weight').values
v2 = df.filter(like='name').values
df['max_weight'] = v1[df.index, v1.argmax(1)]
df['max_name'] = v2[df.index, v1.argmax(1)]
df
Out[921]: 
   a_weight  b_weight  a_name    b_name  max_weight  max_name
0        10         5    John   Michael          10      John
1         1         2    Jake  Michelle           2  Michelle
2        21         3   Alice       Bob          21     Alice
3         2         1  Ashley     Brian           2    Ashley
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick assuming you only have 2 weight columns:

```py
df["max_weight"] = df[["a_weight", "b_weight"]].idxmax(axis=1)
mask = df["max_weight"] == "a_weight"
df.loc[mask, "max_name"] = df[mask]["a_name"]
df.loc[~mask, "max_name"] = df[~mask]["b_name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `idxmax` to find the column names; then use `factorize` + numpy advanced indexing to get the names:

```
df['max_weight'] = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('weight')].idxmax(axis=1)
df['max_name'] = (df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('name')].to_numpy()
                  [np.arange(len(df)), df['max_weight'].factorize()[0]])
```

Output:

```
   a_weight  b_weight  a_name    b_name max_weight  max_name
0        10         5    John   Michael   a_weight      John
1         1         2    Jake  Michelle   b_weight  Michelle
2        21         3   Alice       Bob   a_weight     Alice
3         2         1  Ashley     Brian   a_weight    Ashley
```